# Is it possible to use a Spring Bean in a Condition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I would like to create a Condition which uses a special Bean. Is it possible?

i.e. something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyCondition implements Condition{

    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return myBean.isTrue();
    }
}
```

I.e. in some cases I have to get a database session bean and check something in a database before I can say if the condition is true or false.
I need that condition to be used with `@Conditional` annotation then.
I.e. :

```
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
@Configuration
public class Config{
//...
}
```

Comment: Of course, why not?

Comment: @Ashwel, because official docs specify that: "Conditions must follow the same restrictions as BeanFactoryPostProcessor and take care to never interact with bean instances. For more fine-grained control of conditions that interact with Configuration beans consider the ConfigurationCondition interface."

Comment: You could try to get your required beans from the `ConditionContext.beanFactory` at this point, but note that this might cause circular dependency errors if you are not careful.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. As it says in the documentation this is because it might

> cause premature bean instantiation, violating the container and causing unintended side-effects

so in your case, if your condition references a DB bean, the DB might get instantiated before the container is able to fulfil its preconditions.